# IE Developer Toolbar BHO and Developer Tools Watch feature not allowing me to add in debug mode (Using IE 8)

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, ie-developer-tools, watch

I am using IE 8, and the "IE Developer Toolbar BHO" is not working correctly, specifically it won't allow me to add anything to the "Watch" feature, in debug mode.  Where it says "Click to add..." in italics, it's grayed out.  This was after I tried using IE 8's innate debugger, Developer Tools, by the way.  Thinking it's an isolated incident, I attempted to debug multiple websites and I still couldn't add anything to the Watch.  How may I resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I googled around for the same issue and found this question. Not alone at least.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear to work for me either. How has that gone unnoticed? Perhaps nobody's ever attempted to use it :)

A workaround is to type the variable name/expression you're interested in into the textbox at the bottom of the "Console" tab and hit enter. Less than ideal I know, but you are working with IE8 :)

Comment: Thank you for that.  I don't think it's functional, at all.  I say it in jest, but I think Microsoft forgot it existed.

Comment: You can also highlight a variable name in the displayed source, right click on it and chose "Add Watch" this is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I thought I had the same issue, and I even read this page from the MSDN (URL below) and skipped right by the relevant information. In order to add variable to the watch panel you must have the script paused during execution via a breakpoint first. Once a breakpoint is reached the context menu will include the "Add to Watch" command that has been mentioned by others, when you right click over a highlighted variable.

Ref: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)